# Mocking Android's LocationProvider

Tags: android, testing, gps, mocking

Currently I'm testing my android application's LocationProvider by mocking some GPS data from a file in order to temporarily simulate a movement on a real device. Also, I'd like to switch from my mocked data to real data on the fly. The following code works fine for mocking GPS data read from a file. However, when I try to stop mocking the GPS data my current location gets stuck at the last read GPS signal from the file.

Because I don't want to change the code of my actual android application I write my mocked data in the LocationProvider associated with the name `GPS_Provider`. Location based applications can read the mocked data by simply calling `requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_Provider, , ). The tricky part is to reset the GPS  LocationProvider in order to deliver real data again. Here I got stuck and don't know how to set it up again.

```
    private AssetManager assetManager;
    private LocationManager locationManager;

    private String locationProviderName = LocationManager.GPS_Provider;

    private List<Location> allMockedPositions;

    private Handler handler;
    private int position;

    private Runnable runner = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (position <= allMockedPositions.size()) {    
                Location mockedLocation = allMockedPositions.get(position++);
                locationManager.setTestProviderLocation(locationProviderName, mockedLocation);
                handler.postDelayed(runner, 500);
            }
        }
    };

    public MockLocationProvider(Context context) {
        assetManager = context.getAssets();
        locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    }

    public void startMockingLocation(Route route) {
        allMockedPositions = LocationData.getRouteData(assetManager, route, locationProviderName);
        startMocking();
    }

    private void startMocking() {       
        position = 0;
        handler = new Handler();
        handler.post(runner);
    }

    public void stopMockingLocation() {
        locationManager.clearTestProviderLocation(locationProviderName);
        stopMocking();
    }

    private void stopMocking() {
        handler.removeCallbacks(runner);
    }
```

Comment: You're doing this on the emulator right? Not on a real phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement a `LocationManager` and `LocationListener` to get the current location of the phone and then use that location in your `stopMockingLocation` method. You already have a `LocationManager` in your code but, just as a reference, the documentation on how to set up this callback system can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/location/currentlocation.html) and [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/location/locationmanager.html).

Basiclly you're going to configure your `LocationManager` to get updates from either the wireless `NETWORK_PROVIDER` or `GPS_PROVDER`. This will then feed the new location info to the `LocationListener` if there is a registered change within your specified parameters (you can set a time and distance range within which a change will be registered).

Lastly, in your `LocationListener` you will see a method for `onLocationChanged`

```
private final LocationListener listener = new LocationListener() {      
    @Override     
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {         
    // A new location update is received.  Do something useful with it.           
    }     
};
```

This is what is called when the phone's location changes within the time and distance parameters you define. If all you want to do is get the user's location once your stop mocking, you could simply create an instance variable, store the users location to that variable from within the `onLocationChanged` method, and then access that location from within your `stopMockingLocation` method. Alternatively you could call other methods from within `onLocationChanged` but I cannot make a reccommendation as I am not sure exactly what you are tring to do.

Comment: I simply want to write a application that allows me to start and stop mocking GPS data and switch between reals and mocked GPS data

Comment: I got that - what I'm saying is that you need to collect the GPS data so that you can use it once you stop mocking. If you use the locationlistener to get GPS data then, whenever you stop mocking the location, you can simply use the GPS location. There's no other way to get GPS location excpet with a locationlistener/locationmanager

Comment: I could also use getLastKnownPosition of my LocationManager before I start mocking my GPS data but that's not the point. Since I'm writing my mocked GPS inside the LocationProvider associated with the string GPS_Provider, I can't use it in the regular way after I'm done mocking. Every time I access the cleared LocationProvider with requestLocationUpdates(...) I receive the last mocked location. After I'm done mocking GPS data I could add the lastKnownPosition to receive it from the LocationProvider but that wouldn't allow me to track the actual movement after mocking.

Comment: Hmm. Can you use a separate class? One that only records location outside of this mocked location class and then retrieve the location that way? I understand the difficulty is mocking within the provider. Trying to think of a work around.